# Why do class functions in PHP not need semicolons at the end?

Tags: php

For example...

```
public function processRowSet($rowSet, $singleRow = false){
    $resultArray = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowSet)){
        array_push($resultArray, $row);
    };

    if ($singleRow === true){
        return $resultArray[0];
    };

    return $resultArray;
}
...and then the next line continues without an issue
```

When I was first starting with OOP PHP, I made the error of putting a semicolon at the end and it took me about an hour to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Um, the whiles and ifs don't need semicolons either.

Comment: I'm not sure where you would have seen semi colons there in any example or tutorial. As bolt said - same for if and while. I can't believe it works at all

Comment: there is `function` keyword for identifying that line theny why need another??

Comment: It works because a semicolon on its own is considered a Null Statement (do nothing).  That's why a common mistake is to write a loop like:

    for ($a=0; $a=10; $a++);
        print $a;

The semicolon after the loop is the do-nothing command that it will execute 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between statements and expressions:

- If-statements, while-statements, functions, and so on are *statements* which do not need to be semicolon-terminated.
- Actual commands are *expressions* (i.e `$foo = bar()`). Standalone expressions require semicolons, probably since they don't have braces to signify expression ends.

PHP borrows this syntax from C.

Comment: The correct answer is that the difference is between *statement groups* (which use braces)  (you incorrectly call these "statements") and *statements* (which use semicolons) (you incorrectly call these "expressions").

Answer (score 5):

Why?

Because the author/s of the PHP programming language designed the language as so.

When you create some code in php the following process happens:

1. A pre-parser parses your file, looking for syntax errors.
2. A post-parser parses your file, looking for runtime errors.
3. The content of the file is changed into assembler code.
4. The assembler code changes into machine code, which then runs your program.

The authors of the programming language made the parser allow semi-colon after statements, that's WHY you're allowed to do so. (They use the brackets instead).

Some programming languages require you to use a semi-colon because the parsing process can be very difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, you never need a semicolon after a block-closing brace.  Your code should look like this:

```
public function processRowSet($rowSet, $singleRow = false){
    $resultArray = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowSet)){
        array_push($resultArray, $row);
    }

    if ($singleRow === true){
        return $resultArray[0];
    }

    return $resultArray;
}
```

A semicolon on its own is considered a Null Statement (do nothing). That's why a common mistake is to write a loop like:

```
for ($a=0; $a=10; $a++); 
    print $a;
```

The semicolon after the loop is the do-nothing command that it will execute (nothing) 10 times and then print out an "11".  This is equivalent to writing:

```
for ($a=0; $a=10; $a++) {
    ; // do nothing
}
print $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Many programming language does not require a end of statement ie. ';' after a function block, or any other type of block statements like if, for, while . We do not define end of block by terminator as blocks are already confined in {}. Its due to how the code is being executed by the language parser/compiler.